# Operator overload ()

Tags: c++

Why the result of this 3?
I don't underastand what "Class1() :a(3)" means.

```
class Class1
{
private:
    int a;
public:
    Class1() :a(3)
    {       
    };

    Class1(int f) 
    {
        a = (int)f;
    };
};
```

And this is  Main

```
int main(void)
    {
        Class1 c11;
        c11.print();
    }
```

Comment: Open up any good beginner's C++ book and it'll explain what member initialiser lists are.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *"I don't underastand what `Class1() :a(3)` means."*

It's called member initializer list, and initializes the class member variable `a` with the value `3`.

Also see [What is this weird colon-member (“ : ”) syntax in the constructor?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1711990/what-is-this-weird-colon-member-syntax-in-the-constructor)

Answer (score 0):

Class1() is a constructor.

A constructor is a function that initializes the values of the members of the class when an object is created. Here, when you use Class1 c11 , the constructor is called and the value c11.a is initialized as 3.

Class1() : a(3) means that the constructor is initializing a as 3.

To know more about constructors visit these links

http://www.tutorialspoint.com/cplusplus/cpp_constructor_destructor.htm

http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/constructor_destructor_ordering.html

Answer (score 0):

It's a ["member initializer list"](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/initializer_list). Member variable `int a` is simply **initialized** with the value `3`. Assigning the value to `a` **within** the constructor would be an **assignment**.

An initializer list initializes member variables (through the own or a parent class's constructor). If a member variable is not contained in the list, it is **default-initialized**, i.e. their default constructor is called, which is, for member variables of type `int`, an initialization with value `0`.

Conclusion:

Initializing a member variable in the constructor itsself **first** calls the default constructor and **then assigns** the particular value to the member.